# what is the name and which es version of this syntax belongs? export default { [PROPERTY](){} }

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax

For instance, I have seen a code like this

```
const SET_SOMETHING = 'SET_SOMETHING';
export default {
   [SET_SOMETHING](){}, // <=== ARRAY PROPERTY SYNTAX?
};
// or
export default {
   [SET_SOMETHING]: () => {}, // <=== ARRAY PROPERTY SYNTAX?
};
```

what is the name of this(ARRAY PROPERTY inside export default) syntax? and which es version does this belong?
Because I would like to read more about this but I don't know what does it call.
Many thanks.

Comment: ES6 [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

Comment: @OriDrori Thanks a lot.